# $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_{1/2}^1t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a real function with $f(0)=0 ,$ differentiable for $x \neq0 $ and $f'(x)= \frac{e^x}{3f^2(x)+2f(x)+1}$. There also exists a $x_0, 0<x_0<2 $ s.t. $f(x_0)=1$

I am asked to calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_{1/2}^1t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2)$ (not sure if it's clear but t is raised to the power of $1/f(x)$ )

---

I have found : $f^3(x)+f^2(x)+f(x)=e^x-1$ , $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0)=1$, $\int_0^{x_0} e^xf(x)= {{23\over 12}} $ Although I am not sure how many of these will be needed

---

EDIT

I saw the DCT theorem answer but it got me wondering if it can be solved in a "simpler" more elementary way. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: One can do it without DCT, however, it is somewhat annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$, one has
$$ f(x)=f'(c)x $$
where $c\in(0,x)$. So if $x\to0^+$ then $c\to 0$ and hence $\lim_{c\to 0}f'(c)=f'(0)=1$. This implies that for small $x>0$,
$$f(x)>0, \ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1{f(x)}=+\infty. $$
So for small $x>0$,
$$ |t^\frac{1}{f(x)}\sin(t^2)|\le1, t\in[1/2,1] $$
and hence one has, by DCT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_{1/2}^1t^\frac{1}{f(x)}\sin(t^2)= \int_{1/2}^1\lim_{x\to 0^+}t^\frac{1}{f(x)}\sin(t^2)=0.$$

Comment: I'm really not trying to be annoying but I'm not really sure what happened in the last two steps , also im not familiar with DCT so if you could please explain a bit more it would be really nice

Comment: DCT means the Dominated Convergence Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem. It is about the exchange of order for integral and limit.

Comment: alright thats really helpful thank you so much for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Slight spin on the previous answer avoiding the dominated convergence theorem.

You have already established that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, $f'(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$. This implies $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} 1/f(x)=+\infty$ and in particular $0<1/f(x)-3$ for $x\in (0, \delta)$ for some small $\delta>0$.

Pick $x\in (0, \delta)$, then we have for all $\xi\in (0,1/2)$ (as $\vert \sin(t^2) \vert \leq 1$)

\begin{align*}
0&\leq \left\vert \int_{1/2}^1 t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2) dt \right\vert
\leq  \int_{1/2}^{1} t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3} dt 
= \int_{1/2}^{1-\xi} t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3} dt + \int_{1-\xi}^{1} t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3} dt \\
&\leq (1-\xi)^{1/f(x)-3} + \int_{1-\xi}^1 1 dt \\
&=(1-\xi)^{1/f(x)-3} + \xi.
\end{align*}
Now let $0<\varepsilon<1$. Then we can pick $\xi=\varepsilon/2$ and get
\begin{align*}
0&\leq \left\vert \int_{1/2}^1 t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2) dt \right\vert \leq (1-\varepsilon/2)^{1/f(x)-3}+ \varepsilon/2.
\end{align*}
Now, as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} 1/f(x)=\infty$, we can pick $\eta_\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $x\in (0,\eta_\varepsilon)$ we have
$$ (1-\varepsilon/2)^{1/f(x)-3} \leq \varepsilon/2. $$
Thus, for all $x\in (0, \eta_\varepsilon)$ we have
$$ 0\leq \left\vert \int_{1/2}^1 t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2) dt \right\vert \leq \varepsilon. $$
As this works for all $\varepsilon>0$ we get
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \int_{1/2}^1 t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2) dt =0. $$